# Pandas how to group data into ranges?

Tags: python, pandas

I have numeric data in a column from each value is from 1-28.

I need to do a value count and a percentage by splitting it into two categories 1-21, and 22-28.

I need something like:

```
Category   cout  percentage 
1-21       xxx      xxx%
22-28      xxx      xxx%
```

How can I do this in pandas?

I've tried may different things from cut and groupby but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: do you want the category to be exactly 1-21 and 22-28 or you want it to be flexible later (maybe change it into 1-10, 11-20, 21-28 or etc) ?

Comment: the later is what I want